# Loop Break functionality?

Tags: loop

Does ExpressionEngine support the "break" functionality in its loops?

```
{exp:channel entries
  channel="foo"
}
  {if some_arbitrary_condition}
    {!-- Do Break(exit the loop) --}
  {/if}
{/exp:channel entries}
```

Comment: You might see here http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/200488/. May be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there is no break functionality for Expression Engine as of now.

The closest thing that can emulate it is using this code

```
{if count == "1"}
…output count here…
{/if}
```

It would still do the conditional for each iteration but you only execute the code inside once.

Thanks to @Bhaskar Yadav for the link

Answer (score 0):

I think Mark Croxton's Switchee plugin might do what you're looking for, but not in that syntax. It'll let you create multiple case statements and also accepts regex patterns.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee